# How to set the date to the today date in sonata admin

Tags: date, sonata-admin

i want to set the date to today date in sonata admin. i used this code in my admin class but just the year setted to today year:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('dateDeroulement','date',
             array('years' => date('Y'),2020))
```

Answer (score 1):

In "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.4",

and symfony 4 worked this way:

In configureFormFields():

```
$formMapper->add('closeTimeUTC', DateTimeType::class, []);
```

In entity:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->closeTimeUTC = new \DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the `getNewInstance` method of the admin class to pre set the date on that entity.

**Example AdminClass**

```
class ExampleAdmin extends Admin
{
    public function getNewInstance()
    {
        $instance = parent::getNewInstance();

        // Set date to today
        $dateTime = new \DateTime();
        $dateTime->setTime(0, 0, 0);

        // Instance points to the entity that is being created
        $instance->setDateDeroulement($dateTime);

        return $instance;
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        ....
        $formMapper
            ->add('dateDeroulement','date', 
                    array('years' => date('Y'),2020))
        ...
    }
}
```